# Fragment. Open URL when item from list view is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having trouble with getting a string and passing it to another fragment. the string-array has URLs.

**Im trying to get string from fragment1**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_url_list, container, false);

        final String[] urlarray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_urls); //got array list from string.xml good
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,urlarray);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//here im trying to get string when clicked and send it to another fragment
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)  {

                Bundle extras = new Bundle ();
                extras.putString("url", Arrays.toString(urlarray));
                MyWebFragment fragment = new MyWebFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(extras);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

**Second fragment:**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, container, false);

        
        WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String url= bundle.getString("url");  //trying to get string from fragment1 and open url
        webView.loadUrl(url);


       /* webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });*/
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        return view;
    }
```

I have mainactivity and two different fragments.
Both fragments are already in main activity. When running the program I can see the listview to the left and webview to the right (two frame layouts).. If I use webView.loadUrl() to load any site it works correctly. But, the program has to open the clicked url.

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way is to use custom chrome tabs

```
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0"
```

Usage(Kotlin)

```
val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
            val colorInt : Int = Color.parseColor("#009639")
            builder.setToolbarColor(colorInt)
            val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context , Uri.parse("UrlString"))
```

Reffer link:  https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/

Comment: Thanks for this easy way to show web-page with close button. It's worked!